# Allow a QEMU VM access to the internet, while blocking access to LAN

Tags: networking, firewall, qemu, kvm-switch, libvirt

**Host OS:** Arch linux

I have read the qemu and libvirt documentation regarding networking but still cannot get this to work. I am trying to set up a Linux virtual machine for general use that has access to the internet, but **does not** have access to my physical LAN. Theoretically making the virtual machine as isolated as possible on the networking side of things; dropping ICMP and SSH traffic etc.

**Topology**:
Just a rough example. Missing representation of physical and virtual NICs, network bridging and IP subnets.
[image]

**Virtual network:**
NAT mode is the default network mode and from what I have read, seems to be the ideal one for my use case. I assign the network an IP subnet and DHCP server and setup firewall rules on my router/gateway to drop traffic on the forward chain from said IP subnet to the LAN. However with this completely blocks internet access alongside LAN access.

Should I add some local firewall rules on the host to drop the traffic to the LAN?

If so, could you provide an example/template firewall. I have never got my hands dirty with host-local firewall applications and rules.

Comment: You should use a different subnet for the Virtual machine.  By using the same subnet the machines can likely communicate directly and bypass the firewall.   Isn't clear what firewall/router you are using but deny LAN2 access to LAN should do it.